# ASP.Net MVC4 return html page with directory listing instead of its internal javascript script file

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

When I try to deploy on a iis (win server 2016), a few CSS and scripts reference apears to load with error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeujR.png)

This references previously configured in the BundleConfig class doesn't work on deploy, but when I debug locally all works perfect.

Any idea of this?

Answer (score 0):

Often this means that you named your bundles incorrectly. Bundle's virtual path shouldn't match with existing folders on server. So try to rewrite destination virtual path on bundles config.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that the error comes from a JS that was located in other folder. I put all the JS behind /Content/ folder and everithing works well.